# Titanium: Change the Color of the Contact Picker's Bar

Tags: iphone, titanium

Is it possible to change the color of the toolbar displayed in the Contact Picker displayed by:

```
Titanium.Contacts.showContacts();
```

Thanks!

Comment: hi, you get any answer ......?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not available in the current implementation of Titanium mobile.